# Azure: Pricing of deployment slots for an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-deployment-slots

Azure: Pricing of deployment slots for an Azure App Service.

Using an S1 App Service Plan, my web site has up to 5 slots for web app staging.
How are those slots charged?  Are they billed only if used?  Included in the S1 fee? or something else.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Michael, it part of the app service plan itself.  You will see for example that for Azure App Services that standard and premium instances include staging slots.  Standard has 5 and premium has 20.  They are not priced separate from the plan.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Comment: where is the 5 and 20 slots specified? I cannot find this info

Comment: It's not on that page. You can see it on the Scale up tab in the Portal, and also in documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: I found the number of staging slots per tier here (couldn't find it on the page linked to above): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

Comment: I have a premium app service plan with 1 slot and I reckon I'm getting charged for it :(

Answer (score 27):

The staging slots are included as part of your App Service tier.  A used slot does not cause extra charges as far as the App Service pricing goes.  But since they are part of a shared resource, usage on a staging slot can effect the overall performance of the VM.  However, a staged site may incur other costs on Azure.  If the running of that slot consumes blob data storage, send queue messages, etc. then those costs will still have to be paid as part of the overall application framework.

Answer (score 0):

[Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal)

> Each App Service plan tier supports a different number of deployment slots. There's no extra charge for using deployment slots.

[Azure App Service plan overview: How does my app run and scale?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-does-my-app-run-and-scale)

> When you create an app in App Service, it's part of an App Service plan. When the app runs, it runs on all the VM instances configured in the App Service plan. If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances. If you have multiple deployment slots for an app, all deployment slots also run on the same VM instances.

Answer (score -8):

Should be pay per usage. Azure App Service is charged base on the plan that you are on, all your slots and main site are on the same VM which will cause usage of compute hour.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

[image]

Comment: staging slots are free and limited by plan

Comment: The question is specifically about the effect of adding deployment slots therefore this answer is misleading.